# How to avoid Hibernate Envers cross join?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-envers

i need to take the entries from **entity_name_aud** and **revinfo** tables using filter for **contract_id**.

```
...
AuditQuery query = auditReader.createQuery()
            .forRevisionsOfEntity(EntityName.class, false, true)
            .add(filter);

 return query.getResultList();
}
```

Hibernate:

```
    select
        e0_.id,
        e0_.content_id,
        e0_.rev,
        r1_.rev,
        e0_.revtype,
        e0_.content,
        r1_.revtstmp,
        r1_.updated_by 
    from
        entity_name_aud e0_ 
    cross join
        revinfo r1_ 
    where
        e0_.contract_id=? 
        and e0_.rev=r1_.rev
```

Unfortunately, this code generates cross join between those tables, which results in bad performance. Is it possible to change the cross join to left join.

I checked Hibernate Envers documentation and didn't help much.

PS: I have simplified the hibernate log for the cross join.

Comment: Why do you have a CROSS JOIN with a join condition in the WHERE clause? Can't you do a regular INNER JOIN instead?

Comment: Hibernate does that. For me, that is the long way to write inner join and I don't understand why Envers does that.

Comment: What strange database version are you using that does not see this SQL is the same as an inner join?